# How to search MongoDB-Documents on different nesting levels?

Tags: mongodb, profiling, profiler, analysis, nested

I'm currently analyzing a `system.profile`-Collection of a MongoDB-database. I'd like to find Queries that  have a stage with an `COLLSCAN` oder `IXSCAN`. My problem is, that the field `stage` can occur on several levels (`...`: shortened JSON):

```
{
    "op" : "query",
    "ns" : "spt.coll",
    "query" : {
        "user" : "userC"
    },
    "ntoreturn" : 1,
    ...
    "millis" : 0,
    "execStats" : {
        "stage" : "PROJECTION",
        "nReturned" : 1,
        ...
        "transformBy" : {
            "settings.arr" : 1
        },
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "nReturned" : 1,
            ...
            "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "nReturned" : 1,
                ...
                "matchTested" : 0
            }
        }
    },
    "ts" : ISODate("2015-07-30T09:16:22.551Z"),
    "client" : "127.0.0.1",
    "allUsers" : [ ],
    "user" : ""
}
```

In the above example the stage occurs on 3 levels:

1. `"execStats.stage"`
2. `"execStats.inputStage.stage"`
3. `"execStats.inputStage.inputStage.stage"`

There might be even deeper nested stages. **Is there a way to return all documents, that have a `stage: "IXSCAN"` oder `stage: "COLLSCAN"` on any of those nesting levels?** or do I have to run a query for each nesting level?

I tried to use following function referring to [How to find MongoDB field name at arbitrary depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31197652/how-to-find-mongodb-field-name-at-arbitrary-depth) , but unfortunately that gives an error:

```
db.system.profile.find(
  function () {
    var findKey = "stage",
        findVal = "COLLSCAN";

    function inspectObj(doc) {
      return Object.keys(doc).some(function(key) {
        if ( typeof(doc[key]) == "object" ) {
          return inspectObj(doc[key]);
        } else {
          return ( key == findKey && doc[key] == findVal );
        }
      });
    }
    return inspectObj(this);
  }
)
```

Error-message:

```
Error: error: {
    "$err" : "TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object\n    at Function.keys (native)\n    at inspectObj (_funcs1:6:25)\n    at _funcs1:8:22\n    at Array.some (native)\n    at inspectObj (_funcs1:6:35)\n    at _funcs1:8:22\n    at Array.some (native)\n    at inspectObj (_funcs1:6:35)\n    at _funcs1 (_funcs1:14:16) near 'rn Object.keys(doc).some(function(key) '  (line 6)",
    "code" : 16722
}
```

---

To reproduce the above JSON, use the following code:

```
use spt

db.coll.drop()

db.coll.insert([
  {settings: {arr: ["a", "b"]}, user: "userA"},
  {settings: {arr: ["c", "d"]}, user: "userB"},
  {settings: {arr: ["e", "f"]}, user: "userC"},
  {settings: {arr: ["g", "g"]}, user: "userD"},
])

db.coll.ensureIndex({user: 1})

db.setProfilingLevel(0)
db.system.profile.drop()
db.setProfilingLevel(2)


db.coll.find({user: "userC"}, {"settings.arr": 1}).limit(1).pretty()
db.system.profile.find().pretty()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find MongoDB field name at arbitrary depth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31197652/how-to-find-mongodb-field-name-at-arbitrary-depth)

Comment: Using the code directly from the duplicate works for me without error. But the point was the lesson. How to find is do code like that. Chage it if you need to work around other data types. But as I said. I just started the slow query profiling, executed one query. And then can immediately hit something in the collection just by cut and paste from above. No errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you mention is thrown by `Object.keys` when the object is not an enumerable.
An easy way is to catch and ignore the error:

```
db.system.profile.find(
  // Returns all documents, for which this function returns true.
  function () {
    var findKey = "stage",
        findVal = "COLLSCAN";

    function inspectObj(doc) {
      // Object.keys(doc) works only for enumerables like (Arrays and Documents)
      // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys
      // The incoming Object might also be e.g. `ISODate("2015-07-29T08:20:42.768Z")`
      // Thus you need to catch (and ignore) TypeErrors thrown by Object.keys()
      var contains = false;
      try {
            contains = Object.keys(doc).some(function(key) {
              cVal = doc[key];
              if ( typeof(cVal) == "object" ) {
                // Recursive call if value is an Object.
                return inspectObj(doc[key]);
              } else {
                return ( key == findKey && doc[key] == findVal );
              }
            });
      } catch(TypeError) {
        // ignore TypeError
      }
      return contains;
    }

    return inspectObj(this);
  }, {op: 1, ns:1, query: 1}
)
```