# MongoDB - search in document's nested objects

Tags: mongodb

I have `documents` in my `collection` similar to `foo`. These `documents` can have a nested `parent` object which also can have a nested `parent` object and so on..

```
foo: {
    caption: "Italian",
    code: "",
    id: 17,
    parent: {
       caption: "Restaurants",
       code: "",
       id: 9,
       parent: {
          caption: "Food and Drink",
          code: "food_and_drink",
          id: 1,
          parent: ""
      }
   }
};
```

How can I search for a mathch in `foo.parent.id` and all it's nested `parent` objects (if there are any)? Should I use `$in`? Recursively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give to the method `find(...)` a custom function that's gonna check for you the nested levels.

### Example

```
 db.collection.find(
  function () {
    var findKey = "find-this",
        findVal = "please find me";

    function inspectObj(doc) {
      return Object.keys(doc).some(function(key) {
        if ( typeof(doc[key]) == "object" ) {
          return inspectObj(doc[key]);
        } else {
          return ( key == findKey && doc[key] == findVal );
        }
      });
    }
    return inspectObj(this);
  }
)
```

### To look at

[StackOverflow: How to find MongoDB field name at arbitrary depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31197652/how-to-find-mongodb-field-name-at-arbitrary-depth)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to use recursion,Below code will be very helpfull to you,try this

```
    db.getCollection('foo').find().
      forEach(function(x) {
          function t(x){
               if (x.parent) {
                 t(x.parent);
               } else {
                 print(x.caption);
               }
         } 
         t(x)
     });
```

You will get the last parent of all document and get any field of that parent instead of caption 
I have used `caption`

If above code doesnt work put a small change

```
if(x.parent != "") instead of if(x.parent)
```