# MongoDB: Getting the Document ID from deeply nested subdocument

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database

I have stored a Directed Acyclic Graph as a document as follows:

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("58595041cfdc46100f92a985"),
   "modelType" : "Graph",
   "name" : "Graph 1",
   "connections" : [
        {
           "id" : ObjectId("5859504dcfdc46100f92a986"),
           "name" : "node 1",
           "connections" : [
               {
                  "id" : ObjectId("58595057cfdc46100f92a987"),
                  "name" : "node 2",  // shows that node 1 is connected to node 2
                  "connections" : [
                      {
                         "id" : ObjectId("58595057cfdc46100f92a987"),
                         "name" : "node 3", // shows that node 2 is connected to node 3

                      },
                      {
                         "id" : ObjectId("5859506ccfdc46100f92a988"),
                         "name" : "node 4"  // shows that node 2 is connected to node 4
                      }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "id" : ObjectId("5859506ccfdc46100f92a988"),
                  "name" : "node 3"   // shows that node 1 is connected to node 3
               }
           ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Now, given any connection Id, I would like to know which graph it is belonging to.

I think that this can be resolved by having a query which looks recursively into the document to find the subdocument having the specified document ID.

Please provide some information about how to write the query to get the GraphID from the connection ID.

Comment: Do you tried using `$where`? For example: `Graph.findOne({ $where: { 'connections._id': connId }});`.

Comment: Yeah, remove the where and try again: `Graph.findOne({ 'connections._id': connId });`

Comment: Wait a second. In you tags says "Mongoose". Are you using Mongoose or native MongoDB?

Comment: I tried the following query: db.test.find( { $where: function() { return (this.connections.id == 8) }}) ===> It gave no result.

Comment: I am using Mongoose, but also i am trying to run it on Mongo Shell

Comment: @guzgarcia, this query works fine for 1 level search, it doesnt work for n level search

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131185/discussion-between-guzgarcia-and-maulik-soneji).

Comment: I think I have to implement a recursive structure which is mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31197652/how-to-find-mongodb-field-name-at-arbitrary-depth

Comment: MongoDB v3.4 has a recursive graph lookup feature https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/#pipe._S_graphLookup