# How to project only what was found in Mongo when searching at an arbitrary depth?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a similar problem to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31197652/how-to-find-mongodb-field-name-at-arbitrary-depth), which is searching at an arbitrary depth.

However, I want to retrieve only what was actually found and the hierarchy above it, not the entire document which looks like the default behaviour of `find()`

> If you specify no projection, the `db.collection.find()` method returns **all fields of all documents** that match the query.

For example, I have an object that look like this*:

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "template": {
        "a": {
            "node1": {
                "options": {
                    "configuration": "true"
                }
            },
            "node2": {
                "options": {
                    "configuration": "false"
                },
                "a":{
                    "node1": {
                        "options": {
                            "configuration": "false"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "b":{}
            },
            "node3": {
                "options": {
                    "configuration": "false"
                },
                "a":{
                    "node1": {
                        "options": {
                            "configuration": "true"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "b":{}
            }
        },
        "b": {
            "node1": {
                "options": {
                    "configuration": "true"
                },
                "a":{
                    "node1": {
                        "options": {
                            "configuration": "true"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "b":{
                    "node1": {
                        "options": {
                            "configuration": "false"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to find any match where `configuration = false`,  and expect to retrieve only the match and everything above it like:

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "template": {
        "a": {
            "node2": {
                "options": {
                    "configuration": "false"
                },
                "a": {
                    "node1": {
                        "options": {
                            "configuration": "false"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "node3": {
                "options": {
                    "configuration": "false"
                }
            }
        },
        "b": {
            "node1": {
                "options": {
                    "configuration": "true"   <-- still get this as it has a matching child
                },
                "b": {
                    "node1": {
                        "options": {
                            "configuration": "false" <-- Matches here
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I had a look at `$project`, but I just don't know how to use it in this case.

**OBS:**

* Before you say anything about how the data is structured, I understand that is does not look like a good design without any context, but similar to the question I've mentioned this data is also got from some sort of XML importation (kind of) and anyway it's already attend our needs, and there is no way to change it.

Comment: How do you query this?

Comment: @greyfairer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31200456/2137778

Comment: It works, but it return all my documents, as every one of them has at least one case the condition matches

Comment: there isn't any way to programmatically use $project in a `.find()` query. You could use the aggregation pipeline, but I'm not sure I see any possible usage that really benefits you.

Comment: Yeah, I see. I thought it could be "easy" :P

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [positional operator '$'](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) as in:

```
db.students.find( { grades: { $elemMatch: {
                                            mean: { $gt: 70 },
                                            grade: { $gt:90 }
                                          } } },
                  { "grades.$": 1 } )
```

But that's only on one level.

There's no big advantage of doing this on the server side over doing it on the client side. The hardest part of the operation is the search itself, so that should be as optimal as possible. For the projection, MongoDB only implemented some basic requirements, and leaves more complicated stuff to the client.

For optimization, we did a separate query with a separate index at each depth:

```
db.brand.ensureIndex({products.navigations.subNavigations._id : 1}, {unique : true, sparse: true, name : "unique.subnavigation1.id"})
db.brand.ensureIndex({products.navigations.subNavigations.subNavigations._id : 1}, {unique : true, sparse: true, name : "unique.subnavigation2.id"})
db.brand.ensureIndex({products.navigations.subNavigations.subNavigations.subNavigations._id : 1}, {unique : true, sparse: true, name : "unique.subnavigation3.id"})
```

Comment: There isn't any array, why do you need the positional operator?

Comment: Hmm, yeah, you got a point. It would be a more-or-less effective solution if it were nested arrays with a 'type' attribute instead of the random names as keys...

Comment: I was just thinking of what you said about doing this on the client side. I've tried first, but I thought that it could be "easier" and more performatic having the server delivering it. Now I'm coming back to the first approach

Comment: If performance is an issue, you definitely should change your DB Schema. Or create a new denormalized collection next to it.

Comment: When doing at client side, I didn't try to trully test performance. I just felt it was too much do it on the client, but I'm rethinking it now.

Comment: But anyway, thank you very much @greyfairer. I always tried my best, but this time I may have fallen on the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: If you're worried about performance, `$where` is the slowest operator in the mongo toolset, so you're already off to a bad start. I'd recommend finding a better format for your data.