# Search by regex on field name

Tags: mongodb

Is there an inbuilt way to search the field names using regex in a MongoDB database? The documentation lists a $regex field to search the field value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this either at arbitrary depth using JavaScript evaluation of a [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) clause:

```
db.collection.find(
  function () {
    var findKey = new RegExp("^start");

    function inspectObj(doc) {
      return Object.keys(doc).some(function(key) {
        if ( typeof(doc[key]) == "object" ) {
          return inspectObj(doc[key]);
        } else {
          return findKey.test(key);
        }
      });
    }
    return inspectObj(this);
  }
)
```

Or if you have MongoDB 3.4 and are only looking at the "top" level of the document you could do this with `.aggregate()` and `$objectToArray`:

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
     "finder": { "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT" }
  }},
  { "$match": { "finder.k": /^start/ }  }
 ])
```

This is because `$objectToArray` takes an "object" and translates into an array of objects with keys `"k"` and `"v"` for each "key" and "value" of the supplied object. We can do this to the entire document using `$$ROOT`. So we are basically turning the "keys" into "data" that can be searched.

With the data transformed, you can then use simple "dot notation" and a regular [`$regex`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) query expression to match the value of the "key".

So the aggregate method is best for "flat" documents, or dealing with a "known depth", and the JavaScript approach is best where the key could be nested at any level.

---

Attribution to : [How to find MongoDB field name at arbitrary depth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31200456/2313887) for the essential parts of the JavaScript version of the search. Only modified for the regular expression.