# MongoDB - query embedded documents

Tags: mongodb, database

My problem is that I have very embedded structure

example

```
{
  "id":"1",
  "name": "a",
  "ids":[
    {
      "id":"3123",
      "name": "a",
      "ids":[
        {
          "id":"842387",
          "name": "a",
          "ids":[
            {
              "id":"2313",
              "name": "a",
              "ids":[
                ...
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

is there different way to find embedded object than "dot noation"?
For example I would like to do query like this

```
db.doc.find({"id":"2313"}).pretty()
```

And just receive

```
            {
              "id":"2313",
              "name": "a",
              "ids":[
                20x... 
              ]
            }
```

My questions are:

1. Is is possibile to query like above? - without "dot notation"
2. Or is there different database that will allow me do such a things?

Comment: Simply replace the values of `findKey` with `"id"` and `findVal` with `"2313"` or whatever your required values are and apply to the function shown in [How to find MongoDB field name at arbitrary depth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31200456/2313887). Usage of `$where` is not a great idea as is also mentioned in the answer. You should restructure data.

Comment: but this approach will return me whole document instead of piece of it. Now I created more flat structure (every document have its own id and array with child ids - instead of nesting) but how can I agregate it? Because this db.test1.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
            from: "test1",
            localField: "array",
            foreignField: "array",
            as: "aggregated"
        }
}]).pretty() works only for one level

Comment: [Ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). This one is answered already