# find({}) doesn't return correct result

Tags: mongodb, node-mongodb-native

in my NodeJS application, I'm trying to retrieve some data from my Mongo database that has certain conditions. This is the query that I use:

```
itemCollection.find({
    "$where" : function(){

        var searchKey = 'find-this';
        var searchValue = 'please find me';

        return searchInObj(obj);

        function searchInObj(obj){                            
          for(var k in obj){       
            if(typeof obj[k] == 'object' && obj[k] !== null){
              if(searchInObj(obj[k])){
                return true;
              }
            } else {
              if(k == searchKey && obj[k] == searchValue){
                return true;
              }
            }          
          }                         
          return false;
        }       
    }    
}
}).toArray((error,result) => { console.log(result.length});
```

When I look at the result, I see that the query returned with the whole data set, however if I try to run the same query directly in the database (with Robo 3T), the result that I get contains only the relevant entries.
So what's wrong with that query?

Note: I'm not using Mongoose in my application.

Comment: Not an expert at this but could it be that you need to pass obj into your function, or is it globally available?

Comment: I'm not sure actually, I used this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/36934292/5587350, to construct my query.

Comment: try passing 'this' instead of obj

Comment: @NeilLunn, I got a bit confused, the code in my answer is from accepted answer, however the link I provided in the comments is another answer, so which one should I use?

Comment: No the code is not from the accepted answer. You copied from an incorrect ( though strangely upvoted even though it will not work ) answer. The accepted and correct answer is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31197652/how-to-find-mongodb-field-name-at-arbitrary-depth/31200456#31200456). Note also it's clear you have the wrong one since apart from being identical code, you commented on the incorrect answer as well.

Comment: @NeilLunn, thanks. Do you know if it's possible to update the values that I'm looking for, in the same query? For example every time I find "please find me", I will change it to something else directly in the database.

Comment: You could create a closure, which is a function that returns another function. Then that can be used to populate values fed into the function executed within the `$where`. On the wider scope, I would not recommend any of this. If you have a schema that requires such *arbitrary depth searches*, then it's probably more of a sign that the schema is incorrect and not optimal, and should be revised. Or indeed that MongoDB is maybe not what your particular storage and query solution needs, and possibly something else is better suited. But I'm more inclined to say "redesign the schema".