# How to update MongoDB field name at arbitrary depth

Tags: mongodb

I am currently working with many different documents that contain addresses that are nested  at different depths and I need to migrate the data in it to a different format of address. I wanted to create a request that I could use on all my collections.
Here's an example of a document:

```
{
"foo": 1,
"bar": 2,
"address": {
    "streetNumber": "23"
    "streetType": "rue",
    "streetName": "du stack"
},
"stuff": {
    "baz": 3,
    "gobble": {
        "wibble",
        "address": {
            "streetNumber": "23"
            "streetType": "rue",
            "streetName": "du stack"
        }                
    },
    "plugh": {
        "plove": {
            "address": {
                "streetNumber": "23"
                "streetType": "rue",
                "streetName": "du stack"
            } 
     }
}
```

In this document I want to merge the streetType and streetName and then delete the streetType field so that the address looks something like that:

```
"address": {
        "streetNumber": "23"
        "streetName": "rue du stack"
},
```

I began working on a mongo request but I am still very new to this. I took inspiration from [How to find MongoDB field name at arbitrary depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31197652/how-to-find-mongodb-field-name-at-arbitrary-depth) , but I know this doesn't really apply here because I want to modify the documents and not just return them.

```
db.myCollection.updateMany(
{ $where : 
  function () {
    var searchKey = "streetType";
  
    return searchInObj(this);
  
    function searchInObj(obj){                            
        for(var k in obj){       
          if(typeof obj[k] == 'object' && obj[k] !== null){
            if(searchInObj(obj[k])){
               obj[k].streetName = obj[k].streetType + ' ' + obj[k].streetName;
               delete obj[k].streetType;
               return true;
            }
          } else {
            if(k == searchKey){
              return true;
            }
          }          
        }                         
        return false;
  }
}}, 
{ $unset : { streetType: ""} }
)
```

So yeah it doesn't work, I know it probably looks very wrong I can see it myself, although I found that the $where thing returned the correct documents at least, but I don't know how I can apply the modifications to the nested "address" everytime it finds one.
Now that I think about it it will only go as far as the first occurence of address it finds and it will return from the function, so the solution is probably very different from that.
Any insight would be greatly appreciated !